# How to connect to one's local machine when on the remote for use with sftp

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, putty, sftp

I'm working on a remote server and using PuTTy. I'd like to use sftp to transfer files to my local machine. I need to connect to the local machine in the remote prompt, but how do I find the connection string or the information to do this? I will need to do sftp to connect and after which I can use get/put to transfer between. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there's no NAT in the way? Why not open the SFTP connection from your local machine instead?

Comment: @DanielB Yes I wish I could open the SFTP from my local connection instead but unfortunately I have to do it the other way around. Do you know how to get the information I would need to get for transferring onto my local machine?

Comment: Sure, it's in the `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable. But again: this won't work.

Comment: Again, this won't work? Can you please clarify and explain how I might go about this. @DanielB

Answer (score 2):

When you connect to an OpenSSH server, processes started in your session can take a look at the `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable to get information about the underlying TCP connection:

```
$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION
192.168.2.114 57650 192.168.2.5 22
```

Here, *192.168.2.114* is the client host (running the SSH client), *57650* is the client TCP port, *192.168.2.5* is the server host (running the SSH server) and *22* is of course the server TCP port.

So you can just do something like `echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{ print $1 }'` and try to connect to that.

You cannot get the remote username or password, though some trickery with public key authentication and agent forwarding could save you from having to enter a password.

**HOWEVER** this all will most likely not work. Because today, you are usually behind a NAT firewall. Unless you manually set up a port forwarding, incoming connections will all be rejected or dropped.

When I connect to a host on the internet, it looks a little different:

```
$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION
46.223.226.204 57691 94.130.123.123 22
$ ssh 46.223.226.204
ssh: connect to host 46.223.226.204 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Note how the *client host* is now *46.223.226.204* even though internally it is *192.168.2.114*. I do not have a port forwarding for SSH set up, so the connection fails.

I’m lucky because I still have proper IPv4 connectivity. More and more ISPs however are using Carrier-grade NAT, making things like port forwarding impossible. Connectivity (as in opening a TCP connection) should in general be considered one-way over the internet.

tl;dr: Start the SFTP connection from your PC. It’s the only way.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually possible to do via a reverse tunnel, even if local computer is behind NAT and/or a restrictive firewall. Basically, you have your SSH connection make a tunnel from a randomish port on the server back to the SSH service on your local computer.

First, pick a randomish port that isn't already in use on the server (note: the max possible port is 65535). You'll probably have to guess what isn't in use, but if you happen to guess badly just disconnect, reconfigure for a different port, and try again. I'll use port 54321 as an example.

I don't use PuTTy, but according to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/321132/how-to-start-a-reverse-tunnel-with-putty) and [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ssh-tunneling-putty), what you need to do is go to Settings -> Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels, and put in the randomish port as the Source port, "localhost:22" as the Destination, and select the Remote option below that. Then connect to the server normally.

(If you were using OpenSSH, you'd use something like `ssh -R54321:localhost:22 serveruser@serveraddress` to get the same effect.)

Then, on the remote server, use this to connect back over the tunnel:

```
sftp -P 54321 localuser@localhost
```

Note that the username you use here is the one you use on your local computer, not your username on the server.

BTW, when you do this you're allowing anyone else on the server to potentially also connect back over that tunnel to your local computer. All the usual warnings about SSH security apply: make sure the service on your computer is locked down to only users that *should* be SSHing in, and that those have hard-to-guess passwords.

Ideally, disable password auth in favor of public-key authentication. I think you could store both private and public keys on your computer, and use [agent forwarding](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/pageant-forward.html) to let the server use your local private key to authenticate the reverse connection.